# Erdos discrepancy problem for limited arithmetic progressions

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Does the Erdos discrepancy problem remain true if we restrict the allowed arithmetic progressions to be taken from some set $D$? More formally, For what kind of sets $D$ is this statement true:

Given $C > 0$, and a set $D$ of natural numbers, there is $N$ such that for every finite sequence $f(1), f(2), ..., f(N) \in \{-1, 1\}$, there are $d \in D$ and $n$ such that 
$$\left|\sum_{j=1}^{n} f(jd) \right| > C$$

Is this known to be true only if $D = \mathbb N$? (I haven't read Terry Tao's proof, so I'm not sure if he proved it for $D = \mathbb N$ or something more general.)

PS: I don't know if this is a known problem either. Just something that I was thinking about.

I have some half-baked knowledge about Tao's proof, and I remember reading that he (and the relevant Polymath project) reduced the problem to the problem involving only multiplicative functions, so I guess in this version it would boil down to only using the primes in $D$, or maybe some sort of basis-set of $D$).

Any kind of answers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It became clear early on that multiplicative functions were not the answer and nor were character-like functions. Each chain of limited discrepancy conceals within it other chains (a chain is difference $d$, multiplicative functions essentially work with every homogeneous arithmetic progression having the same sequence as for $1$ or its negative). If the chains aren't all the same you need a (maybe small) family of chains which behave like a group - but essentially you need more than one solution to the problem to build a non-multiplicative solution - and for those solutions to be related.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an alternating sequence of $+1$ for odd numbers and $-1$ for even numbers, every arithmetic progression with odd difference has maximum discrepancy $1$.

The Thue-Morse sequence has some interesting properties in this respect too - see  the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) and [this paper](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10586458.2013.746616) for example

Your question is an interesting one. Odd number differences exclude the prime $2$. What are the minimal sets of odd primes we can exclude? The question of bounded discrepancy seems quite subtle, but excluding the prime $2$ renders it trivial. What is going on there?